# Having a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 error. RECURSIVE FLOODFILL

Tags: java, recursion, indexoutofboundsexception, flood-fill

I am trying to make a flood-fill game that prints out numbers into the console window and allows the user to pick a number in order to "fill" the 2D array with the same number. The objective is to have the 2D array filled with your color. I use a 4-way recursive method to fill these numbers. Any time I run this, and try to input a "color," it throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
     at Board.floodFill(Board.java:57)
     at Board.floodFill(Board.java:68)
     at Board.move(Board.java:47)
     at FloodIt.main(FloodIt.java:30)
```

**Here is my code:**

```
class FloodIt {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Flood-It Game.");
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        System.out.println("How large of a board would you like?");
        System.out.println("I would suggest sizes between 3x3 and 20x20.");
        System.out.println("And colors between 3 and 6.");
        String again="";
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter the one digit number of the board width (3-20): ");
            int size=Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            System.out.print("Enter the number of colors (3-6): ");
            int numColors=Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            Board board=new Board(size,numColors);
            while(!board.finished()) {
                System.out.print(board);
                System.out.print("What color do you choose? ");
                int color=Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
                board.move(color);
            }
            System.out.println("Nice job, you finished in "+board.numMoves());
            System.out.print("Would you like to play again (Y/N)? ");
            again=scan.nextLine();
        } while (again.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
    }
}

import java.util.Random;

/**The board class for the Flood-It game.  This class implements a NxN board filled with numColors colors.
 * The class implements several methods to allow the playing of the game.
 */
class Board {
    private int moves;
    private int[][] board;//a 2D array
    Random rand = new Random();

    /**Constructs a new sizeXsize board filled where each element on the board is a random number between 0
     * and numcolors.  Also initializes the number of moves to zero.
     * @param size the size of the board
     * @param numColors the number of possible entries on the board
     */
    public Board(int size,int numColors) {
        moves=0;
        board = new int[size][size];
        for(int row=0;row<board.length;row++){
            for(int col = 0;col<board[row].length;col++){
                board[row][col]=rand.nextInt(numColors);
            }
        }
    }


    /**Updates the board to fill (from the top left corner) with a specificed color.  
     * Filling stops when any other color is hit besides the one in the top left corner.
     * Play the game at http://floodit.cs.bris.ac.uk/About.aspx to get a better understanding of what
     * this method should do.  You will probably also want to take a look at the algorithm described
     * at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill which describes what this method should do.
     * You are free to have this method call other methods (I would recommend creating a private method that
     * this method calls.).
     * @param color the new color to flood the board with.
     */

    public void move(int color) {
        floodFill(0,0,board[0][0],color);
        moves++;

    }

    private void floodFill(int row, int col, int origColor,int newColor){
        //base case
        if(origColor==newColor){
            return;
        }
        if(board[row][col]!=origColor){
            return;
        }
        if(row<0||col<0){
            //do nothing
            return;
        }


        board[row][col]=newColor;

        floodFill(row,col-1,origColor,newColor);
        floodFill(row,col+1,origColor,newColor);
        floodFill(row-1,col,origColor,newColor);
        floodFill(row+1,col,origColor,newColor);    
    }


    /**returns true if the board is not completely filled with a single color.
     * Otherwise it returns false.
     * @return true if board is all one color
     */
    public boolean finished() {
        //TODO finish this method

        return false;
    }


    /**returns how many times the move() method has been called.
     * @return the number of times the move() method has been called.
     */
    public int numMoves() {
        return moves;
    }


    /**Returns a string representation of the board.  Use tabs between elements of the board.
     * And have every row of the board be a seperated by a newline character.
     * Example:
     * "1\t0\t3\t\n2\t0\t2\t\n1\t0\t1\t\n"
     * @return a String representation of the board
     */
    public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        for(int row=0;row<board.length;row++){
            for(int col = 0;col<board[row].length;col++){
                result += board[row][col]+"\t";
            }
            result+="\n";
        }return result; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indicate line # **57** in your `Board.java` file.

Comment: Ah! I apologize. 
Line #57 is `board[row][col]=newColor;` in the floodFill method.

Comment: Make your `if(row<0||col<0) { return; }` the **first one**. Right at the top of the method.

Comment: Wow. That sure did it. Thank you so much! May I ask why that works?

Comment: Actually, that works sometimes. But when I keep going with trying to get the 2D array, it then throws the out of bounds exception again but this time on the `if(board[row][col]!=origColor){return;}` and the `floodFill(row,col+1,origColor,newColor);` lines.

Comment: As [Samuel already noticed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28757204/2055998): you need to check for upper bounds as well.

Comment: Another (different) issue you might run into is that recursive flood fills are very likely to create a stack overflow.  I suggest doing your DFS iteratively with an explicit stack rather than using the call stack.  Or do a BFS with queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `floodFill` method you do not check if `row` or `col` is within bounds before calling `board[row][col]=newColor`.

Your code:

```
if(row<0||col<0){
        //do nothing
        return;
}
```

should be placed higher up in the function so that it is checked before `board[row][col]=newColor`. It also needs to check if it is greater than the array's width and height.

Correct code:

```
if(row<0||col<0||row>=board.length||col>=board[0].length)
{
   return;
}
```

Comment: Yes I did have that line wrong. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You check for

```
if(row<0||col<0)
```

so both `row` and `col` could be **0**.

Then you have

```
    floodFill(row,col-1,origColor,newColor);
    floodFill(row,col+1,origColor,newColor);
    floodFill(row-1,col,origColor,newColor);
    floodFill(row+1,col,origColor,newColor);
```

so either of the two could become `-1`.

Your code has the following validation sequence:

```
   if(board[row][col]!=origColor){
        return;
    }
    if(row<0||col<0){
        //do nothing
        return;
    }
```

In the first `if` you can have `[-1]`. If you swap the two `if` it won't be possible.